# Arrays have incompatible sizes for this operation (although my arrays seem to match just fine)

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Have the code typed out and have been making minor changes, but cannot seem to get it to compile anymore after coming back to it after a day. It states that my arrays have incompatible sizes for this operation, but they should be the same size throughout the entire operation being completed.

Below is the entirety of my code: **ERROR IS IN LINE 58**

```
% Material Properties of AS4/3501-6 Graphite/Epoxy

E1 = 148e9;   % [Pa] Young's Modulus long.
E2 = 10.5e9;  % [Pa] Young's Modulus trans.
G12 = 5.61e9; % [Pa]Shear modulus
nu12 = 0.3;   % Poisson's ratio

theta = [45 -45 -45 45]; % Fiber orientations for each layer in degrees

t = 0.2; % Layer thickness (each layer has same thickness)

mid_plane_strains_1 = [0.05; 0; 0]; % Mid-plane strains: ex, ey, and gamma_xy (case 1)
curvatures_1 = [0; 0; 0]; % Curvatures: kx, ky, and kxy (case 1)

mid_plane_strains_2 = [0.0500; 0.0250; 0.0125]; % Mid-plane strains: ex, ey, and gamma_xy (case 2)
curvatures_2 = [0.020; 0.010; 0.001]; % Curvatures: kx, ky, and kxy (case 2)

% A, B & D Matrices
Q11 = E1/(1-nu12^2);
Q12 = nu12*E2/(1-nu12^2);
Q22 = E2/(1-nu12^2);
Q66 = G12;

A = zeros(3,3);
A(1,1) = Q11;
A(1,2) = Q12;
A(2,1) = Q12;
A(2,2) = Q22;
A(3,3) = Q66;

B = zeros(3,3);
B(1,3) = 1/2;
B(2,3) = 1/2;

D = zeros(3,3);
D(1,1) = Q11;
D(1,2) = -Q12;
D(2,1) = -Q12;
D(2,2) = Q22;
D(3,3) = Q66;

% Transformation Matrices
T = zeros(3,3,length(theta));
for i = 1:length(theta)
    c = cosd(theta(i));
    s = sind(theta(i));
    T(:,:,i) = [c^2 s^2 2*c*s; s^2 c^2 -2*c*s; -c*s c*s c^2-s^2];
end

% Global Stiffness Matrix
n_layers = length(theta);
Qbar = zeros(3,3,n_layers);
Tinv = zeros(3,3,n_layers);
for i = 1:n_layers
    Qbar(:,:,i) = inv(T(:,:,i)).*[A B; B D].*T(:,:,i);
    Tinv(:,:,i) = inv(T(:,:,i));
end
B_global = zeros(6,6);
for i = 1:n_layers
    z = (i-0.5)*t;
    B_global = B_global + Qbar(:,:,i)*t;
    B_global(1:3,4:6) = B_global(1:3,4:6) + Qbar(:,:,i)*z;
    B_global(4:6,1:3) = B_global(4:6,1:3) + Qbar(:,:,i)*z;
    B_global(4:6,4:6) = B_global(4:6,4:6) + Qbar(:,:,i)*z^2/2;
end

% Global strains (Case 1)
mid_plane_strains_1_vec = [mid_plane_strains_1(1); mid_plane_strains_1(2); 0; mid_plane_strains_1(3); 0; 0];
curvatures_1_vec = [curvatures_1(1); curvatures_1(2); 0; curvatures_1(3); 0; 0];
epsilon_global_1 = mid_plane_strains_1_vec + curvatures_1_vec;

% Compute global stresses (Case 1)
sigma_global = B_global\epsilon_global_1;

% Compute local strains and stresses
epsilon_local = zeros(3,n_layers);
sigma_local = zeros(3,n_layers);
for i = 1:n_layers
    epsilon_local(:,i) = Tinv(:,:,i)*[epsilon_global_1(1); epsilon_global_1(2); epsilon_global_1(4)-curvatures_1(3)*(z-(i-0.5)*t)];
    sigma_local(:,i) = Qbar(:,:,i)*epsilon_local(:,i);
end

% Compute stresses at each point through the thickness
n_points = 10;
z_points = linspace(-t/2, t/2, n_points);
sigma_z = zeros(3,n_points);
for i = 1:n_points
    z = z_points(i);
    for j = 1:n_layers
        if z > (j-1)*t-0.5*t && z <= j*t-0.5*t
            sigma_z(:,i) = sigma_local(:,j) + Qbar(:,:,j)*(z-(j-0.5)*t)*epsilon_local(:,j);
            break;
        end
    end
end
```

Tried to compile code to finish solving my project, but it seems that somewhere there is an array issue. I am expecting there not to be one, since the arrays have been 3x3 throughout the entire process.

Comment: `size(T(:,:,i))` is 3x3 and `size([A B; B D])` is 6x6 on the line throwing the error. These are not the same so you can't do element-wise multiplication. You've given very little context for what you're trying to do, this question would be improved by an [edit] which greatly reduced the code example to a [mcve] if you're not sure why your matrices end up the sizes they are

Comment: I'm sensing you might have been trying to do T^-1 *  [A B; B D] * T, but you cannot do matrix multiplication as @Wolfie notes `size(T(:,:,i))` is 3x3 and `size([A B; B D])` is 6x6. Noting that A, B, and D are all 3x3.